# How to find the relationship between average income and owning a house

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling, spss, discriminant-analysis

I have a sample about the income of 110 households, and I want to see how owning a house is determined by the level of income. Or I want to see the effect of income on school enrollment for boys, girls, and both as three different nominal variables.

I use boxplots as descriptive statistics, but it is not that well adequate.  Any other method of analysis especially in SPSS would be appreciated.

Comment: For prediction of whether someone owns a house, have a look at logistic regression and discriminant analysis. If your enrollment variables are also binary (i.e. enrolled vs not enrolled), those same methods can be applied. In all cases it would be best to have more than one predictor, so hopefully you have information other than household income.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

> For prediction of whether someone owns a house, have a look at
>   logistic regression and discriminant analysis. If your enrollment
>   variables are also binary (i.e. enrolled vs not enrolled), those same
>   methods can be applied. In all cases it would be best to have more
>   than one predictor, so hopefully you have information other than
>   household income.

– Alvaro Fuentes

I would add that the natural starting point is logistic regression, which is more informative than discriminant analysis. However, with your low ample size (110) you should not expect to much. Complement with some visualization of the data, and of the modeling results.